# Is there any example of real-life decidable problem that is not in EXP?

Tags: computational-complexity

In order to illustrate an introduction on computational complexity, I am trying to find examples of real-life problems for every one of the main complexity classes: $P$, $NP$, $EXP$, $R$ and *undecidable*.

The idea is to have at least one problem per class that is easy to explain, and that is not in the previous class (assuming $P ≠ NP$ and $NP ≠ EXP$).

So far, I have:

- $P$: cycle detection in a graph
- $NP$: Travelling Salesman or Tetris
- $EXP$: Generalized Chess or Go
- $R$: ???
- *undecidable*: Halting problem

Any idea for $R$?

Comment: You have the mathematical description of some NEXPTIME-complete problem here, it is up to you to imagine a real-life situation similar to it : https://books.google.fr/books?id=-X39_rA3VSQC&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=NEXPTIME+complete+problem&source=bl&ots=_7raQSsH_u&sig=W6n4IzR9qQPVd8mOif2PzAtKpFg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyw6GZntfMAhWGDMAKHTw1C7UQ6AEISTAF#v=onepage&q=NEXPTIME%20complete%20problem&f=false